How to get WIF private key from wallet.dat in bitcoind
I have a wallet.dat that was generated by bitcoind, and I want to use it in a piece of software that I'm creating that signs multisignature transactions using bitcoinlibjs. My code requires a WIF format private key, so I need to somehow extract the private-key information from my wallet.dat and use this in my software.
I have imported my wallet, and run bitcoin-cli -testnet listdescriptors, and have the descriptor information for my wallet.
How do I extract my private key from wallet.dat, then convert it into WIF format?

This question is similar to: Extract private keys from Bitcoin Wallet. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see converting private key to WIF
